# Tag Assistant says Event Consent State is "granted" even thought default is set to "denied"

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have consent setup on my website.

When the website first loads I send a consent default event with all consent states set to denied.

After I ask the user for consent and communicate that to the tag manager with the consent update event.

Looking at the Tag Assistant before the user responds I can see that the first consent default event was picked up and set: https://imgur.com/XD8LeS0

The problem is all the following events have that same Event Consent State then set to granted even thought I never sent an consent update event: https://imgur.com/9UjAczw, https://imgur.com/W50mBwe, https://imgur.com/kCC5pFv

What is going on here? Shouldn't all the following Event Consent States be set to denied?

I tried sending an update event right after the default request and in that case the denied consent seems to persist through the next triggers.